# Do you say "apart of course" or "of course apart"?

Tags: phrases, writing-style

When phrasing a sentence that goes like this:

> Max gambled all his money away and lost it, <apart of course/of course apart> from his pending multi-million dollar inheritance.

Do you say *apart of course* or *of course apart*?

Comment: “of course” is two words.

Comment: Yeah, what motivates you to remove the space from between "of" and "course"?

Comment: Apologies, ignore that, it's a mistake on my part.

Comment: @DanBron any particular reason why you edited the erroneous spaces back into my question? Also, removing the placeholder for where I want the phrase to be added in the sentence will confuse the reader of the question

Comment: I didn't intend to put the spaces back in, nor remove the placeholder. I just wanted to change your preformatted (code) text to quotes, using blockquote and italics respectively. I must have messed up editing somehow. Let me see if I can fix it. Please hold.

Comment: I see what happened: when I removed the \`\`\` and replaced them with blockquotes, the < apart of course / of course apart > in the resulting markdown was treated like an HTML tag, but since it's not really a tag it was discarded from the rendered result. I've now gone in and replaced the < with `&lt;` and the > with `&gt;`. I don't see what you mean by erroneous spaces. "Of course" is two words, and that's how it's spelled throughout the post. I don't think my edits changed that.

Comment: @DanBron Looks better now, thanks! And I thought you removed the spaces in your edit but it looks like you just changed the formatting.

Comment: '... gambled all his money away and lost it' is irretrievably redundant.

Answer (score 2):

It depends upon whether 'of course' is intended to relate to his loss of money or to his pending inheritance.

Max gambled all his money away and lost it, of course, apart from his pending ... inheritance. In this statement 'of course' could relate either to his loss or to his inheritance.

Max gambled all his money away and lost it, apart from, of course, his pending ... inheritance. In this statement 'of course' only relates to his inheritance.